# How to show bundle products on custom module admin grid in magento 2

Tags: magento2, module, admin, grid, bundle-product

How to show only bundle products on custom module admin grid (not in admin form tabs) in magento 2.Can you please anyone help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable it from admin Catalog/Manage Attributes

Comment: Actually i want to show only bundle products in my custom module admin grid in magento 2 not in magento 1.x

Answer (score 0):

Step to show list of products in admin UI grid:

1) set ui component xml in layout xml file like this :

```
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <uiComponent name="items_items_listing"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

2) Create ui component file inside ui_component folder

3) set provider dependency in di.xml :

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="brand_grid_data_source" xsi:type="string">vendor_name\module_name\Model\ResourceModel\Model_name\Grid\Collection</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
<type name="vendor_name\module_name\Model\ResourceModel\Model_name\Grid\Collection">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">table_name</argument>
        <argument name="eventPrefix" xsi:type="string">vendor_name_module_name_grid_collection</argument>
        <argument name="eventObject" xsi:type="string">vendor_name_module_name_grid_collection</argument>
        <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Vendor_name\Module_name\Model\ResourceModel\Model_name</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
<virtualType name="BrandGridDataProvider" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="collection" xsi:type="object" shared="false">vendor_name\module_name\Model\ResourceModel\Model_name\Collection</argument>
        <argument name="filterPool" xsi:type="object" shared="false">BrandGrrdFilterPool</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
<virtualType name="BrandGrrdFilterPool" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FilterPool">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="appliers" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="regular" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\RegularFilter</item>
            <item name="fulltext" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FulltextFilter</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

Comment: model has your collection data which directly set into your provider

Comment: yes but we are not using any particular table here na.The product data comes from various tables how we can give one table name here.I have a product collection in  block file one function

Comment: protected function _prepareCollection()
        {
            $collection = $this->productFactory->create()->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect("*")->addAttributeToFilter('sku', 'example');
            $this->setCollection($collection);
            return parent::_prepareCollection();
        }